# Finding the limit of an expression using the given condition prescribed by the summation of $arcsinx$

Tags: limits, summation, inverse, trigonometric-series

Given that $$\sum_{r=1}^k \sin^{-1}\beta_r=0$$ for any $k\ge1$

A number $p$ is now defined such that $$p=\sum_{r=1}^k(\beta_r)^r$$

Then what is the value of the limit below?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow p} \frac{(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{x+x^2}$$

This limit can be easily seen to be $\frac{1}{2}$ by putting $k=1$. Then we get $\beta=0$ which in turn implies $p=0$. Now the value of the limit becomes obvious.

But I am absolutely helpless in generalising and proving this result for arbitrary values of $k$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to p} \frac{\ldots}{\ldots}$: Where is $n$ ?

Comment: I actually meant $x$. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this given equation is true $\forall k \ge 1$, let it be true for $k=n$,

Now, it must be also true for $k=n+1$, you can easily subtract the two equations to get $\beta_n=0$.

Thus, you get $$\beta_r=0  ~\forall~ r \in \mathbb N$$

Implying $p=0$